# Vmware ESXI 6.5: Is there a way to combine all 16 vcpus to form 4 vcpus which performs better

Tags: vmware-esxi, hypervisor

I am not talking of overprovisioning of VCPUs. It's actually reverse. A way to combine all available threads to virtualize into a limited number of vcpus to get advantage of ESXI limitations.

I have to run a Single Virtual Machine on VMWARE ESXI 6.5 server. The server ships with 16 cores and 32 threads.

Vmware ESXI has a limitation of 8 vcpu per VM. Is there a way to combine all vcpus and allocate the entire CPU cores to the single VM which means 4 logical threads or 2 physical cores should be mapped to a single vcpu.

I am running an application on top of the VM which does not run on a Physical machine and needs to be hosted on a VSXI Hypervisor.

Comment: In short, no, in length no. 

However I am a bit puzzled as to why you HAVE to run on ESX or rather in a virtualized environment in the first place? There are several free alternatives that allow you to utilize your entire system without artificial limitations.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking based on what you believe to be the VM maximum vCPU limit. Have you read this - https://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere6/r65/vsphere-65-configuration-maximums.pdf

Comment: @Miuku  am trying to run Netapp Ontap select, which runs only on a  Virtualized Environment. Since it's a 2 node infra, only option is VMWARE.

Comment: The limits which @joeqwerty is talking of are for Vsphere. Hypervisor there exists a max 8 vCPU limit.

Comment: So you mean "Is there a way I can do what I need without paying for those features" - no, that's why there's a free version and a paid-version.

Answer (score 4):

Buy a VMware license to remove the limitation you’re trying to work around.

The paid version of the product does not restrict your virtual CPU allocation.

Comment: Or, since it's a single-VM server, just ditch the virtualization and its overhead.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @ewwhite, the following are the [specs/limitations of the free license by VMware for ESXi](https://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor.html):

- No support
- Number of cores per physical CPU: No limit
- Number of physical CPUs per host: No limit
- Number of logical CPUs per host: 480
- Maximum vCPUs per virtual machine: 8

You need a vSphere Essentials or above to remove the 8 vCPU limit per VM.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to combine all vcpus and allocate the entire CPU cores to the single VM which means 4 logical threads or 2 physical cores should be mapped to a single vcpu.

No, that is entirely impossible. You can't somehow "combine" multiple CPUs to a single CPU, neither virtual nor physical. If this were possible the entire parallelization approach would be completely pointless.